# How does TimeValue calculate value of Cashflow?

Tags: implementation-details, finance

The code below calculates the future value of a Cashflow. I intend that the cashflow adds 1 unit on each period for 10 periods, and specifies an effective interest rate of 1% per period. The table is intended to calculate the future value of the cashflow at the end of periods 1 through 10. I thought that the future value at the end of period 1 would be 1.01, since one cash input had occurred, and accumulated 1 period of interest. But this is clearly wrong. I have read the documentation on TimeValue and Cashflow, but I clearly do not understand the meaning of the 3rd parameter to TimeValue when the first is a cashflow. Can anyone shed a little light on this for me?

```
In[1]:= cf = Cashflow[{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}];

In[2]:= Table[TimeValue[cf, .01, n] // N, {n, 1, 10}]

Out[2]= {9.66168, 9.75829, 9.85588, 9.95444, 10.054, 10.1545, \
10.2561, 10.3586, 10.4622, 10.5668}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the 3rd parameter is zero TimeValue calculates the present value (NPV) as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_return#Internal_rate_of_return), i.e.

```
TimeValue[Cashflow[{a, b, c}], r, 0]

= a/(1 + r)^0  + b/(1 + r)^1 + c/(1 + r)^2
```

Each payment a, b, c is discounted to present value according to its timing.  The first payment `a` is at the start so the discounting time period is zero.

The future value is the value at the end of period 3

```
TimeValue[Cashflow[{a, b, c}], r, 3]

= a (1 + r)^3 + b (1 + r)^2 + c (1 + r)^1
```

The first payment `a` has accrued 3 periods' interest; the second one `b` has accrued 2 periods' interest, etc.

The result at the end of period 1 is

```
TimeValue[Cashflow[{a}], r, 1]

= a (1 + r)
```

The progressing value of all the payments at the end of each period is

```
Table[TimeValue[Cashflow[Take[{a, b, c}, n]], r, n], {n, 1, 3}]
```

For the example given

```
cf = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};

Table[TimeValue[Cashflow[Take[cf, n]], .01, n] // N, {n, 1, 10}]
```

> {1.01, 2.0301, 3.0604, 4.10101, 5.15202, 6.21354, 7.28567, 8.36853, 9.46221, 10.5668}

Comment: Thank you @Chris Degnen. That explains it. And then the TimeValue at a period in the middle of the flows is future value of the preceding flows + the present value of the flows still in the future.